# integer array initialization error in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize my array in the following way but get an expression syntax error:

```
int LineOne[ARRAY_LENGTH];//where ARRAY_LENGTH is a constant of length 10
if(SOME_CONDITION_IS_TRUE){
LineOne[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the rest of the code (how you want to use the array), what solution is the best. One other way to do it could be...

```
int* LineOne = 0;
if(SOME_CONDITION_IS_TRUE) {
    static int* init = {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1};
    LineOne = init;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have array literals in "classic" C, except as initializers when the variable is being defined.

In C99, you can use *[compound literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals)* to do this, but you must repeat the type in a cast-like expression before the literal:

```
LineOne = (int[ARRAY_LENGTH]) { 0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1 };
```

Comment: any other way I can initialize the array like above?

Comment: @user1870194 `memset()`, `memcpy()`, etc. or manual one-by-one initialization. Sorry, but much data is much.

Comment: Just keep in mind that using direct memory access is prone to byte order issues when porting to other platforms.

Comment: thanks a million people :) i think @kotlinski answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it that way. You could use an alternate array and copy it:

```
#include <string.h>
…
int values[] = {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1};

int LineOne[ARRAY_LENGTH];//where ARRAY_LENGHT is a constant of length 10
if(SOME_CONDITION_IS_TRUE)
    memcpy(LineOne, values, sizeof(values));
```

Comment: @carlosdc No. `sizeof(values)` is the numbr of *bytes* of the whole `values` array.

Comment: the values {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1} are dynamically changing values based on a condition and this is the reason why I want to initialize LineOne[ArrayLength] later in the code. Any other way? Right now what I'm doing is:`code`if(SOME_CONDITION){LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 0;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 0;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 0;
i++;
LineOne[i] = 1;}`code`

Comment: @user1870194 it is very dependant on how you acquire the values `{0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1}`. If they are in an array then you can `memcpy` the array. Otherwise chances are you will have to make element by element assignement. Note that *not* using `i` as an index but an actual literal (`0`, etc.) is easier.